# Is there a way to invoke a cron job on a certain date/time?

Tags: go, cron

I am using what seems to be the most popular cron package by robfig: https://godoc.org/github.com/robfig/cron. Currently I know that I can invoke an hourly cron job with:

```
c.AddFunc("@hourly", func() { fmt.Println("Every hour") })
```

However I wonder if it is possible to set it so that it only starts after (for example) Sep 1st, 2017? If it's not possible using that package, how else can I achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: Just put something like `if time.Now().After(targetDate)` in the code you're executing.

Comment: @Adrian Then I guess I would need some kind of loop to check the current time every now and then?

Comment: That should be unnecessary since you're already scheduling it to execute on a repeating schedule right?

Comment: @Adrian But I still have no way to make sure that it starts at exactly (for example) 10:30am, since the time check could be invoke every hour like 10am, 11am, 12am, etc...

Comment: It's a cron library, it looks perfectly capable of handling that sort of schedule.

Comment: Using the same go package, to invoke the cron on 9:30 am,10:30 am, 11:30 am etc...

Use

c := cron.New()
c.AddFunc("0 30 * * * *", func() { fmt.Println("Every hour on the half hour")

Answer (score 2):

If you want a custom scheduling, implements your own [*scheduler*](https://godoc.org/github.com/robfig/cron#Schedule), then register the job using [Cron.Schedule](https://godoc.org/github.com/robfig/cron#Cron.Schedule). Below is an example implementation of repeating a CRON job after a certain time:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/robfig/cron"
)

type MyScheduler struct {
    At    time.Time
    Every time.Duration
}

func (s *MyScheduler) Next(t time.Time) time.Time {
    if t.After(s.At) {
        return t.Add(s.Every)
    }

    return s.At
}

func main() {
    c := cron.New()

    //Execute every 2 seconds after a certain time (5 second from now)
    now := time.Now()
    at := now.Add(5 * time.Second) //In your case, this should be: Sep 1st, 2017
    s := &MyScheduler{at, 2 * time.Second}

    c.Schedule(s, cron.FuncJob(
        func() {
            cur := time.Now()
            fmt.Printf("  [%v] CRON job executed after %v\n", cur, cur.Sub(now))
        }))

    fmt.Printf("Now: %v\n", now)
    c.Start()
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    c.Stop()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Adrians Comments,

The package [robfig/cron](http://github.com/robfig/cron) supports cron expression format. To have the cron run 30 mins past every hour viz on 9:30 am,10:30 am, 11:30 am. You could use

> c.AddFunc("0 30 * * * *", func() {})

an implementation to have the cron run after Sep 1, 2017

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "github.com/robfig/cron"
)

func main() {

    // time set to Sep 1, 2017 00:00 Hours UTC
    t := time.Date(2017, time.September, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC) 

    c := cron.New()

    //using cron expression format to have the function run every hour on the half hour
    c.AddFunc("0 30 * * * *", func() {      

        if time.Now.After(t){
        fmt.Println("yay")
        //insert logic block
        } 
     })

}
```

Note: The cron expression format used by this package is different from the standard unix cron format. The expression format used by this package  allows for second precision unlike unix cron format.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. What if I want to start it at 't' and then every 30 minutes after?

Comment: You could achieve the same in two ways :
            
1.  c.AddFunc("0 0,30 * * * *", func() {fmt.Println("Every thirty minutes")})          
2. c.AddFunc("@every 30m", func() { fmt.Println("Every thirty minutes") })